# Where does the standard Android Web Browser keep its history files?

Tags: browser

As in, the included web browser (which isn't Chrome or Firefox).

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad, by the way. But the results might be generalizable to other tablets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the history files will be in the .db file located at `/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/browser.db`

However, you will require root access to be able to work with the files.

Comment: It's also available in a content provider for developers.